# Splitting Tex document in two sections with different formats

Tags: formatting, appendices

I would like to collate my two research papers in one document. One paper is written in one column format (\onecolumngrid) and the other in two column. Each have their own appendices. So the structure should be:

article 1 (two column)

article 1 appendices

---

article 2 (one column)

article 2 appendices

How do I do this? What should I write at end of article 1 appendix so that article 2 text is not considered as part of that appendix.

Comment: A different option would be to take the two pdfs and combine them into a new pdf with the `pdfpages` package.  The section and page numbering would start over.  Would that be sufficient?

Comment: You could create PDF cover sheets for both of them so it is not ambiguous, for example: article 1 cover sheet, article 1, article 1 appendices, article 2 cover sheet, article 2, article 2 appendices. Just put "Research Paper #" or something to that effect on the cover sheets, then you do not have to modify your research article 1 ending.

Comment: @Teepeemm and LaccaseTVersicolor excellent suggestions thanks much.